# Can a factory class (in Factory Design Pattern) be dependent on some other independent factory class?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

**Scenario:**

EntityA -> Independent

EntityB -> Independent

EntityC -> Composed of EntityA, EntityB and some other data

Object creation of `EntityC` requires some data from `EntityA` and `EntityB` and I am confused on how to structure the factory class for `EntityC`

**Approach 1:**

Passing the data required to create `EntityA` and `EntityB` as argument to the `FactoryC.create()` and import `FactoryA` and `FactoryB` to initialize objects inside `FactoryC.create()`

Here, I can keep the logic for object creation completely isolated from my application (which is the main purpose of using Factories), but `FactoryC` would be dependent on `FactoryA` and `FactoryB`

**Approach 2:**

Initializing objects of `EntityA` and `EntityB` in my application (outside the scope of factories) and passing these objects to `FactoryC.create()`

Here, `FactoryC` would be independent of `FactoryA` and `FactoryB` but the downside is that I'll have to put the logic for object creation in my application (outside factories)

Programatically both the approaches will give the same result but I want to know which one will be better in terms of structuring my code. My major concern is to know whether or not to create dependencies between Factory classes.

Comment: Out of these 2 approaches, first one makes more sense since you are beating the purpose of factory in second case

Comment: why you can't initialize both your objects thru the factories and pass this objects in the third factory? it would not be a dependency between factories, it would be dependency of factory and this objects

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How come that `FactoryC` depends on the other two? It depends on entities (parameters) that can be created any way you want (in your case via the other two factories)

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, your factory class can be dependent on other factory classes. It is called factory of factories (Abstract factory pattern)
- It can also be independent, if you use interface for creating a factory of related objects without explicitly specifying their classes. I prefer Approach one.

Answer (score 0):

Approach one is a valid factory pattern since the factory pattern only describes the way of isolating an objects creation.
I think your intention was to ask if a factory pattern can be dependent on other object's classes/models, not on factories (at least that is what you described, but that does not change the fact a factory can depend on another factory).

In Factory C, you could have something like this:

```
public class FactoryC implements Factory {
  public AbstractEntity get() { //or however your entity's abstraction looks like
  EntityA  eA= FactoryA.get();
  EntityB eB = FactoryB.get();
  return new EntityC(eA.someMethod(), eB.someMethod());
}
```